# How to modify position of children inside loop in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a dynamic image gallery from and xml. From my tutorials, right now i've got it so it will constantly add the next thumbnail below the other, which is fine, but I'm trying to figure out how to make it that once it reaches a certain y coordinate, it will move the x coordinate over and stack them again. So that rather one long list of thumbs, it will be a side by side stack. For some reason, I can't get it in my head how something like this would work. My goal is to have a side by side stack that I will end up putting in a movie clip that will be masked to show only 2 stacks at a time. Then when clicking a button will slide it over. I was planning to use the "movieclip.length" to calculate how far over to move it, but i haven't gotten that far yet. This is what I got:

```
var gallery_xml:XML;
var xmlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("xml/content.xml");
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var imageLoader:Loader;

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
gallery_xml = new XML(xmlLoader.data);
info_txt.text = gallery_xml.screenshots.image[0].attribute("thumb");
for(var i:int = 0; i < gallery_xml.screenshots.image.length(); i++)
{
imageLoader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(gallery_xml.screenshots.image[i].attribute("thumb")));
imageLoader.x = 0;
imageLoader.y = i * 70 + 25;
imageLoader.name = gallery_xml.screenshots.image[i].attribute("src");
addChild(imageLoader);
imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showPicture);
}

}

xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
function showPicture(event:MouseEvent):void
{
imageLoader = new Loader();
imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(event.target.name));
imageLoader.x = 200;
imageLoader.y = 25;
addChild(imageLoader);
}
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around what I can do to move things over dynamically without having to write a custom if for each set of positions..  I get the feeling I've totally forgotten how to do algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest one of the following two solutions (untested):

```
var next_x:Number = 0.0;
var next_y:Number = 25.0;
for (var i:int = 0; i < gallery_xml.screenshots.image.length(); ++i)
{
    // ...
    imageLoader.y = next_y;
    imageLoader.x = next_x;

    next_y += 70;
    if (next_y > THRESHOLD)
    {
        next_x += X_OFFSET;
        next_y = 25.0;
    }
}
```

That is, just keep track of where your next image will be placed and adjust that coordinate accordingly when you exceed thresholds. If you want to use your `i` variable, you'll have to calculate what row and column the image will be placed at:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < gallery_xml.screenshots.image.length(); ++i)
{
    // ...
    var row:int = i % MAX_ITEMS_PER_COLUMN;
    var column:int = i / MAX_ITEMS_PER_COLUMN;
    imageLoader.y = 25 + row * 70;
    imageLoader.x = column * COLUMN_WIDTH;
}
```

Comment: imageLoader.x = Math.floor(column) * COLUMN_WIDTH;

Otherwise your column will go diagonally.

Comment: row and column are integers, so they don't need flooring afaik